# How to add 2 more emails to the following form

Tags: forms, email, submit, addition, carbon-copy

Hi can anyone please help me I want to send the form data to 2 more email address but I dont know where to add those 2 emails. The one that is already there is working perfectly.

```
<form id="feedback" name="feedback" method="post">
<ul class="email-form">
<li>
<label>Name Surname</label>
<input type="text" name="full-name">
</li>
<li>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email">
</li>
<li>
<label>Contact Number</label>
<input type="text" name="contact">
</li>
<li>
<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
</li>
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');        
$fullname = $_POST['full-name'];
$email_from  = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$body = "<p style='padding-bottom:10px;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;'>You have received a new message from EPG website.</p><p style='font-family:arial;font-size:12px;'>Name: ".$_POST['full-name']."<br />Email Address: ".$_POST['email']."<br />Contact Number: ".$_POST['contact']."<br />Message: ".$_POST['message']."</p>";
$mail->SetFrom('Info@mysite.com', 'Feedback');
$address = "Info@mysite.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Information Desk");    
$mail->Subject    = "feedback"; 
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
if(!$mail->Send())
{}
?>
<li>
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```